# Webassets + Typescript, cannot resolve symbols/modules

Tags: python, typescript, flask, webpack, webassets

I have a flask project with the following structure:

```
├─ app.py
├─ project
|  ├─ __init__.py
|  └─ static
|     └─ typescript
|        └─ app.ts
└─ typings
   ├─ globals
   |  └─ ... # multiple imported ts libraries
   └─ index.d.ts
```

I'm using a webpacker integration called [Flask Assets](https://flask-assets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I've set up the compilation like so (in `__init__.py`)

```
ts = get_filter('typescript')
ts.load_paths = [
    #os.path.join(config.APP_ROOT, '..', 'typings'), # doesn't do anything :/
    os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'typescript')
]

assets.register('javascript', Bundle(
    'typescript/app.ts', 
    filters = (ts, 'jsmin'),
    output = 'js/app-%(version)s.js'
))
```

My app.ts is, more or less,

```
class SomeClass {
    ... various class methods, using things like jQuery and CryptoJS
}
```

no imports - I'm not really sure whether or not I need them.

The specific error I'm getting is

```
Cannot find name 'JQuery'.
../../../../../var/folders/5t/4x0gmsdx0dbbgv_fr3cv3x6m0000gn/T/tmphFTSQo.ts(7,17): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'CryptoJS'.
../../../../../var/folders/5t/4x0gmsdx0dbbgv_fr3cv3x6m0000gn/T/tmphFTSQo.ts(10,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.
... a bunch more about other symbols
```

Answer (score 0):

I *kind of* solved it...

```
glob_string = os.path.join(config.APP_ROOT, '..', 'typings', '*', '*', '*.d.ts')

assets.register('javascript', Bundle(
    glob.glob(glob_string),
    'typescript/app.ts',
    filters = ('typescript', 'jsmin'),
    output = 'js/app-%(version)s.js'
))
```

basically I just "manually" add all the definition files to the bundle (using glob). It's not sufficient to just add the `index.d.ts` in the root of the typings dir as the typescript filter copies the `.ts` to a temp file (in `/tmp`) before compiling and the paths in `index.d.ts` are relative.

it should also be noted that `ts.load_paths` does nothing...